# Smartface publish process stops with AdMob

Tags: admob, publish

I'm using AdMob in my project. I checked the use AdMob checkbox. When I tried publish my project, publish process stops at "installation packages are creating" step.

I tried it with emulator, the result was same.

What should I do for making it work?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error used NodeJS component to pack the iOS Publish. In windows environments the NodeJS installer fails to create the npm folder under app Data.

https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-enoent-stat-cusersuserappdataroamingnpm-on-windows-7

Basically follow those steps for fix:

1. Press Win + R keys to open run dialog
2. Type %appdata% and press run
3. Create a folder named "npm"